# Передача массива в Twig

Tags: php, twig

Имеется **многомерный** массив $categories_arr:

```
array (size=4)
  'Первая' => 
    array (size=1)
      'От первой' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1-1' => 
            array (size=2)
              9 => string 'от 1-1' (length=8)
              11 => string 'от 1-1' (length=8)
  'Вторая' => 
    array (size=1)
      5 => string 'От второй' (length=17)
  4 => string 'Третья' (length=12)
  'Четвертая' => 
    array (size=1)
      8 => string 'от четвертой' (length=23)
```

В PHP я его могу перебрать функцией:

```
function ShowTree($arr)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($arr as $key => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)){
            echo "<li>$key</li>";
            ShowTree($a);
        }else{
            echo "<li>$a</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Однако я использую шаблонизатор Twig, как перебрать этот массив там (вывести список категорий иерархично)?

Comment: шаблоны инклудить в твиге можно? параметры передавать туда можно? Если здесь рекурсию пишите, то и там инклудьте сам-себя.

Comment: Твиг можно расширить своими фильтрами и функциями. В шаблоне будет выглядеть как `{{ categories|tree }}` или `{{ tree(categories) }}`

Answer (score 0):

*teran* натолкнул в правильную сторону и удалось решить задачу:

> шаблоны инклудить в твиге можно? параметры передавать туда можно? Если здесь рекурсию пишите, то и там инклудьте сам-себя

Сделал отдельный файл шаблона cat.twig который сам себя инклудит и делает рекурсию

```
<ul>
    {% for key, item in categories_arr %}

        {% if item is iterable %}
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
            {% include 'admin/cat.twig' with {'categories_arr': item} %}
        {% else %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```